# Tesseract and iOS error?

Tags: iphone, ios, tesseract

I'm using Tesseract in my iPhone app, I started from a sample app where Tessdata works.
When I export the necessary libraries in my project I get the following error:

```
Error opening data file /var/mobile/Applications/56987B01-F4A8-480D-B209-3842452035E4/Documents/tessdata/eng.traineddata
Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to the parent directory of your "tessdata" directory.
Failed loading language 'eng'
Tesseract couldn't load any languages!
```

Obviously I've imported the 'Tessdata' folder as reference folder, but I can't figure out why I get this error. How can I solve it?
Thank you in advance.

EDIT: Another detail: Tesseract works on the simulator, while fails on the device.

Comment: Yes, it is the same if I check or don't check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved canceling and reinstalling the app on the device!